# DevExpress gridview how to edit invisible column

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am using devexpress gridview and I want to edit invisible column.

Here is a part of my gridview;

```
<dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="COSTCENTERID" Visible="False"
                VisibleIndex="7">
</dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
```

As you can see visible property is set to False so it doesn't appear on the form. I tried to add DataItemTemplate and EditTemplate tags but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `EditFormSettings` Visible to True should solve your problem

```
<EditFormSettings Visible="True" />
```

Look also at [this sample](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E256.aspx)

Comment: I was agreed with you until I tried. 
<EditFormSettings Visible="True" /> 
tag only shows field name but I can't set any value into field. In my case  COSTCENTERID references another table so 
I set its value from combobox. If I add <EditFormSettings Visible="True" / > only COSTCENTERID text appears on form, 
combobox still unvisible

Comment: Then you should explain better what you can't do in your question. So we can understand exaclty what is your problem